# Creating HowTo section for Open Source Software tools or best practices in GIS Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion

I sometimes try to embed  examples and scripts into the Q&A discourse and wonder if we could build a browsable well structured HowTo section for things like the usage of tools or best practice solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have described in your very brief question sounds like Canonical Q&As.  In principle I think they can be accommodated within focussed Q&A on Main, but they should still conform to the protocols that are in place for any Q&A that is to be hosted on Main.

However, I think by [searching this site for `canonical`](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=canonical) and looking for canonical Q&As on Main, any successes that we have had creating and maintaining them have been few and far between.

I suspect the reason is that we as volunteers underestimate how much effort is involved in creating and maintaining them until we have done one or a few, and run out of steam.

<s>An initiative that you may want to follow is [Warlords of Documentation: A Proposed Expansion of Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow).  If providing documentation, in addition to focussed Q&A, can be shown to work on Stack Overflow, then in time we may see it spread to GIS SE.  However, I think anything like that here is still well into the future.</s>

Personally, the terms "HowTo" and "Best Practice" are ones that attract me to open questions to assess whether they really belong amongst focussed Q&A, and I often find that they do not, because I think they tend to use unclear language or are designed to try and attract multiple answers.  Focussed Q&A is about trying to find a single answer, notwithstanding that there may be multiple (usually 5 or less) candidates for that offered, so that users can vote as to which they think answers the question most clearly.

Comment: For my personal understanding if I do Q&A. I have to live with the a trade off between the public or people driven solution finding process, that contains **sometimes a teaching concept** and the **repetion of answers** within a discourse to present material / solutions that are missed or distributed over the WEB or GIS SE as teaching material?

Comment: @huckfinn You have placed a question mark on what looks like a statement.  Can you clarify what you are asking in this comment, please?

Comment: Your answer is a very good one and I've rushed over Warlords of Documentation stuff and see that the "Creation of HowTo..." has more side effects in a community sense, I not reflected before. One solution cold be to consider your own Q&A stuff as a **trade of** and handle the repetition part for myself and the question part: Is it really a trade off.. ..sorry for the inner dialog outside..